# JRequest::setVar vs. input->set

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Somehow the Joomla 3 method of setting the view for redirecton is not the same as the deprecated way.

Deprecated:

```
JRequest::setVar( 'view', 'objects' );
```

Joomla 3:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->set( 'view', 'objects');
```

The redirections does not work with the new version (joomla3). Why?

Answer (score 0):

The below is how to redirect in joomla 3

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect(URL);
```

Comment: Thanks, i know that ;)

Comment: Hi mike, what i mean by that is you need to build the link yourself then pass it to redirect.

Comment: I know, that's not the problem. The redirection was Joomla 3 ready all the time.